# Using form_for with nested resources. "Undefined method _index_path"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to upload files on a form, using Carrierwave. So far, I've managed to 'nest' one model onto another, but now I'm having trouble to do the 'form_for' correctly.

The idea is to setup a page (index) that would list the photographs (Fotografias) corresponding to each  individual (Individuo), and have the ability to add new ones in the same page.

I have the following models:

#### fotografia.rb

```
class Fotografia < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :individuo

  mount_uploader :title, ArchivoUploader
end
```

#### individuo.rb

```
class Individuo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fotografias
end
```

Controllers:

#### fotografias_controller.rb

```
class FotografiasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_individuo, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_fotografia, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
     @fotografias = @individuo.fotografias
     @new_foto = @individuo.fotografias.build
  end

  def set_individuo
    @individuo = Individuo.find(params[:individuo_id])
  end

  def set_fotografia
    @fotografias = Fotografia.find(params[:id])
  end

  def fotografia_params
    params.require(:individuo).permit(:individuo_id, :title)
  end
end
```

`title` is the field that holds the file information in the model.

#### index.html.haml:

```
=form_for [@individuo,@new_foto] do |f|
  .row
    =f.file_field :title, :class => 'hidden'
    =f.label :title, 'New Fotografia', :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary'
```

I read that this might be a pluralization issue, but I don't think that's the case. These are my routes:

#### routes.rb

```
  resources :individuos do
    resources :fotografias
  end
```

#### rake routes output:

```
    individuo_fotografias GET    /individuos/:individuo_id/fotografias(.:format)          fotografias#index
                          POST   /individuos/:individuo_id/fotografias(.:format)          fotografias#create
 new_individuo_fotografia GET    /individuos/:individuo_id/fotografias/new(.:format)      fotografias#new
edit_individuo_fotografia GET    /individuos/:individuo_id/fotografias/:id/edit(.:format) fotografias#edit
     individuo_fotografia GET    /individuos/:individuo_id/fotografias/:id(.:format)      fotografias#show
                          PATCH  /individuos/:individuo_id/fotografias/:id(.:format)      fotografias#update
                          PUT    /individuos/:individuo_id/fotografias/:id(.:format)      fotografias#update
                          DELETE /individuos/:individuo_id/fotografias/:id(.:format)      fotografias#destroy
```

I apologize for the Spanish nomenclature, and other language mixups.

When I try to load `http://localhost:3000/individuos/3/fotografias` I get the following error: "undefined method individuo_fotografia_index_path for #<#:0x007fa05c5d44a0>", with the line responsible for the error being `=form_for [@individuo,@new_foto] do |f|`.

Any clues of what I'm missing?

## Solution

Per answer by TK-421, I made this change to the form_for:

```
=form_for [@new_foto.individuo, @new_foto], :html => { :multipart => true }, :url => {:controller => 'fotografias', :action => 'create'} do |f|
```

This would ensure that it's going to the CREATE action in the `Fotografias` controller. Just to be thorough, here's the create action in the controller:

#### fotografias_controller.rb

```
def create
  @fotografia = @individuo.fotografias.new(fotografia_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @fotografia.save
      format.html { redirect_to individuo_fotografias_path, notice: 'Fotografias Actualizadas' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the route output and error above, it appears that Rails is looking for `individuo_fotografias_path` (instead of `individuo_fotografia_index_path`).

But I'm not sure if that's your intent, based on the `form_for` example you provided.

You might try adding the `url` parameter to your form helper to be more specific: `url: individuo_fotografias_path`.

Or otherwise try some of the longer-form options of the helper as defined in the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) until you get it working the way you'd like.

Comment: I'm not too sure if that's where it has to land. I'm currently trying to put a button on the form that will load a new image, so that it can be saved to the database. The 'save' action would be on the same page (I think), but the error had me incredibly confused cause it's asking for 'index_path' when there isn't one.

Comment: Btw, I tried your suggestion and the error is now gone, but I still don't know if it actually works. Will test and update when I have results.

Comment: Whelp, error's gone, don't need to hear any more. Lalalalalala. ;)